# Are optional arguments required to be at the end of the argument list in PHP method calls?

Tags: php

```
function dosomething($var1, $var2, $var3='somevalue'){
..
}
```

What about

```
function dosomething($var3='somevalue',$var1, $var2 )
{
}
```

Can we latter call doSomething(,1,2);?

This seems to generate compile error though.

Comment: an 'option' `function dosomething($args){}` `doSomething(array());` then you have a little more 'controll' of the apporach

Comment: I would think that the fact that it generates parse errors would answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

from [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected.

In case you want to have flexible number of arguments, you can mess with `func_num_args()`, `func_get_arg()`, and `func_get_args()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to experiment, you can always do:

```
dosomething(['', $var1, $var2]);
```

And in the definition:

```
function dosomething (array $Param) {
  // Put them into individual variables (only if you want)
  $Opt = $Param[0];
  $val1 = $Param[1];
  $val2 = $Param[2];
  }
```

With this you can even do:

```
dosomething([1 => $var1, 0 => '', $var2]);
```

And it will work the same

Notes:

- As an experiment is a fun  thing to do. I wouldn't use the code above for anything serious
- `['a', 'b']` for arrays only since PHP > 5.4. For PHP <= 5.3 less, use `array()` instead.

Comment: Well you can just call `dosomething(NULL, $a, $b)` and rely on `func_get_args()` in function body, which returns the arguments array. Still, functions with too many arguments AND the chance that some of them are sometimes null is smell of bad design to me.

Comment: I agree about the smell design, but for the sake of experimentation, I still find the array giving you many more flexibility (changing order if you change the indexes) while *simple* (type hinting and no need for extra code inside the function).

Answer (score -3):

According to your topic question. Yes, optional argument could be placed everywhere. But it's useless(when optional arguments goes first) except on case. When you using type hinting and null as default value.

Pointless example (for now)

```
function dosomething($var3='somevalue',$var1, $var2 )
{
}
```

You cannot use default value of first argument. [Default argument values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Permissible example

```
function dosomething(stdClass $var3=null,$var1, $var2 )
{
}
```

You could pass null in first argument. [Type Hinting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

P.S. But there is propose to [skip optional parameters](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/skipparams). If it would be accepted and released you could define optional every where in a method.

Comment: Answer updated. Please review it.